# Split Python code into several files which share the same variables

Tags: python, file

I want so split my 5000-lined code into several `.py` files.

The problem is that I use the same variables, like for example objects, or other variables, in both files.

How could I make the files to share variables?

Just to be clear, I don't want to "send" thousands of variables from a file into another, like that for example:

**main.pyw**

```
import other_file

foo = 'any_value'
other_file.send(foo=foo)
```

**other_file.py**

```
shared = {}

def send(**args):
    global shared
    for arg in args:
        shared[arg] = args[arg]
```

At the moment I have to scroll down for a minute to find the class I am looking for, and I want to avoid that; but I want the program to run as if all the code was in one file. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Why don't you want to use function parameters? That's a feature of the language to make it easier to split up code into modules, and to reduce duplication. Why wear boxing gloves when playing the piano?

Comment: The way you describe is the way to go. You can't import variables from `main.pyw` into `other_file.py`, that would leed (a) to a circular import and (b) to a second version of `main.pyw` in memory.

Comment: I use global variables pretty much everywhere: multithreading to load files while something else is displayed depending of another thread, a textbox which needs like 10 variables to run (ugly when you pass thousands of arguments in a function)

Comment: I have to say that I use file splitting to kind of "move" a part of the code, and I would like the program to behave like as if I merge the files. I want the splitting to be only visual.

Comment: @D_00 I am not encouraging you to continue that style as I also think functions modules and parameters are the way to go.
Still, you could have a preprocessor (shell-script) that concatenates all your source files and then run the result of that operation.

Comment: You will probably need a refactoring to not rely on global variables. A solution would be to create a `state` object where you put all these variables and that you pass as argument to the functions in the other files

Comment: So there is no other solution than using parameters? No global variable could be used in the entire script? What is the better solution then: using only one script, placing tons of parameters in each function, or rewriting the entire program? I am all the more reluctant about the last solution as I have been working on this project for almost a year now...

Comment: Globals are generally problematic. Splitting code into functions *is* how to move code. Passing parameters is *the way* of controlling scope and avoiding confusing side-effects. If you find your parameters are often clustered together, it suggests you introduce an object to represent the concept and behaviour based on those parameters. See https://refactoring.guru/introduce-parameter-object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the ideas shared in this page, I found what I was looking for.

To split the code, I:

1. Read it entirely to make a list of all the global variables
2. Moved every global variable possible into classes (for example `dead` becomes `player.dead`, `screen` becomes `game.screen` as I already had `player` and `game` classes)
3. Split the code by putting the classes in the other files
4. Imported the modules in every file (I know, this is slow)
5. Sent the remaining global classes from the main file into the other files